# How to set up a zip code for a guest user before he's buying? WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to WooCommerce and recently made a simple shortcode for guest users to enter their zip codes which will adjust the prices of the shop.

```
function set_zip() {
    $bool = is_user_logged_in();
    if($bool == false){
        echo "<div id=\"zip-check\">
            <form action=\"\" method=\"post\">
                <label for=\"zip-input\">Please enter your zip code:</label>
                <input type=\"text\" id=\"zip-input\" name=\"zip-input\" pattern=\"[0-9]{5}\" title=\"5 character zip code\">
                <input type=\"submit\">
            </form>
        </div>";
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'set_zip', 'set_zip' );

add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );
function process_post() {
    if( isset( $_POST['zip-input'] ) ) {
        $bool = is_user_logged_in();
        if($bool == false){
            $zip = $_POST['zip-input'];

            global $woocommerce;
            $woocommerce->customer->set_shipping_postcode( $zip );
            $woocommerce->customer->set_postcode( $zip );
        }
    }
}
```

I know the code's not perfect yet, but it kinda works for now.
When a guest user adds a product to his cart and afterwards enters his zip code it works perfectly. Even if he deletes the products from the cart the shortcode will still update his zip code. But when the guest user enters the zip code before adding products to the cart the zip code won't save. Why is this and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can check whether the cart is empty is or not. If the cart is empty you don't allow guest to enter the code. (the zip code is of no use anyways if the user has not added in product in the cart)

Can you try following function.

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );
function process_post() {
    if( isset( $_POST['zip-input'] ) ) {
        $bool = is_user_logged_in();
        if($bool == false){
            $zip = $_POST['zip-input'];

            global $woocommerce;
            if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 0 ) {
                $woocommerce->customer->set_shipping_postcode( $zip );
                $woocommerce->customer->set_postcode( $zip );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but I might have asked the wrong question. I want the zip code saved no matter if the guest user has a product in his cart or not. Like the product prices will update when he enters his zip code, but I don't wanna force him to first pick a product and then see it's real price.. hope that makes it more clear. Is there a workaround for this?